# Spring Boot profile specific properties

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Sprint Boot, and would like to have *multiple* profile specific property files.  The docs state:

> In addition to application.properties files, profile specific
>   properties can also be defined using the naming convention
>   application-{profile}.properties.
>
> http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

However I have multiple properties files (e.g. `db.properties`).  I'm loading currently load this non-profile specific file as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( {"classpath:db.properties"} )
class DataSourceConfig  {
    @Value("db.server") String server;
...
}
```

How can I combine these two things together, so it loads `db-dev.properties` like Spring Boot does for `application.properties`

It sounds like it should be easy, but I can't work out how to do it?!

Comment: According to the docs it works just the same.

Comment: I tried db-dev.properties with a @Profiles("dev") annotation and it didn't read the db-dev property in.  Do you have a link to the docs where it says that?

Comment: There is no such link because it doesn't work that way. Only Spring Boot config files have the "x-<profile>" convention. For `@PropertySource` you would need to define one per profile with an explicit file path. (In short if you are using Spring Boot, `@PropertySource` might not be the right tool, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 1):

Java -jar my-spring-boot.jar --spring.profiles.active=test you can set profile.active=your environment via commandline

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you use `@PropertySource`. The [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profile-specific-configuration) say:

> Profile specific variants of both application.properties (or application.yml) and files referenced via **@ConfigurationProperties** are considered as files are loaded.

Comment: Ah, I'm not using `@ConfigurationProperties`.  Was hoping to avoid needing to use that as it requires extra beans (e.g. `DbPropertiesHolder`) & complexity.  Ideally would be able to just use the `@Value("")` annotation for properties within my datasource bean.  I've edited the question to make that clearer

Comment: @Mark Isn't the point of `@ConfigurationProperties` that you don't need `@Value` as the properties are mapped automatically? For your case it seems like a perfect fit. Correct me, if I'm wrong.